# Will Aerodiesel engines replace Avgas engines?

Tags: piston-engine

I've been following aviation for the last 20 years and have seen particularly since the last 10 a lot of talk of aero-diesel engines for light aircraft. The idea being they're cheaper to run using Avtur rather than expensive Avgas.

I'm surprised that in 10 years since I first really saw this mentioned not much has changed. There are a few new aircraft available and retrofits, but by and large engines are still traditional in new aircraft.

Is it likely that aero-diesels will replace traditional aircraft engines any time soon?

Comment: I feel like this is all opinion based... After 10 years, who knows what could happen?

Comment: Things don't change very quickly in the world of light GA. Many of the light airplanes flying today were built between the 1960s and the 1980s (at least that's the case here in the U.S.) When you can buy a used plane for \$20k - \$30k or a new one of a similar model for $300k, it's not hard to see why a lot of people opt for older used planes. Also, the cost of developing and certifying new hardware is often prohibitively expensive compared to the relatively small demand.